# Google Compute Platform - How to accept traffic only from a Target Proxy?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

[GCP Target Proxies](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/target-proxies) are used to provide a public entry point to HTTP(S) backend services.

Is there any way to accept traffic *only* from the Target Proxy, and not directly?

Comment: What is your intention? Do you actually mean you don't want to expose external IP for the backend instances?

Comment: Yes. It seems a bit odd to set up a proxy, but then be able to hit the thing you're proxying directly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to assign external IPs to your backend instances. When [creating instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/insert), you have 3 choices:

- networkInterfaces[].accessConfigs is undefined, no external IP;
- networkInterfaces[].accessConfigs[].natIP is undefined, use ephemeral external IP;
- networkInterfaces[].accessConfigs[].natIP is defined, use static external IP.

If you are using gcloud, use `--no-address` flag with [gcloud compute instances create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create) for no external IP case.

For existing instances with external IP, you can delete the accessConfig, see [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/configure-instance-ip-addresses#unassign_ip) and [API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/deleteAccessConfig).

BTW, [Connecting to instances that do not have external IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#sshbetweeninstances) might be useful to you.

Comment: Sorry, was off work when the bounty expired. When I get a chance, I'll try your suggestions and then re-raise a bounty and apply it accordingly.